# importing txt file and manipulating string to do calculations?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

In VB2010 I need to process a text file which has multiple lines as follows:

```
Student name, 65, 42, 71, 55
Student name 2, 40, 42, 54, 45
etc.
```

I need to process the file, finding:

1. the overall end of year mark and grade each user received
2. the student who got the highest mark
3. the average overall mark
4. the list of students who achieved a particular grade that the user can specify.

Grades: 70% - 100% = D, 60% - 70% = P1, 50% - 60% = P2, 40% - 50% = P3, 0% - 39% = F

I am trying to put a data structure into Public Class

```vb
Structure Student
    Dim name as String
    Dim Paper1 as String
    Dim Paper2 as String
    Dim Paper3 as String
    DIm Paper4 as String.
End Structure

'I am also trying to to do an array
Dim Students() as Student

'Open txt File

Dim FileStreamReader As IO.StreamReader
FileStreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("c:/textfile.txt")
```

Read the File one line at a time

```vb
While not fileStreamReader.EndofStream
    Dim linein as String
    linein = FileStreamReader.readline()
```

I have two main questions:

1. Am I on the right track and if so,
2. Any ideas how I can go about manipulating the information from the txt file? I have been trying for days but I keep getting errors!

Comment: Is it possible that you could store this information like so:
___
"Paul Smith; 23,75,77,59,81" or "Paul Smith;23,75,77,59,81" or "Paul Smith ; 23, 75, 77, 59, 81"
___
?

Comment: No it needs to be seperated by coma as above. Any ideas? I have been trying to use mid, len and instr but being honest I am not sure how to use them properly

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a dedicated csv parser to parse lines in the file. Do not use regular expressions. Do not use String.Split(). Do not try to write your own. You can use the Microsoft.VisualBasic.TextFieldParser class.

You should not use a struct with fields that can be changed. Make it a class instead of a Structure, or make it all the fields read only (no public Set option) and only change the fields in the constructor.

Comment: Sorry Joel - I am kind of new to this. Thanks for the advice - I will google the textfieldparser class