# Load certain values from text file with StreamReader

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I'm a novice at Visual basic so I need a little help getting started on a project I'm working on.  I open a text file containing Student names and grades using a `StreamReader` but I want to select certain values from the text file (e.g. their highest grade, averages and overall marks).  Would I be best off creating an array to display these values or writing functions to retrieve the data I want?  I'm at a bit of a loss and don't want to waste my time so any suggestions would be very welcome.

data is stored as a txt file as follows student name,grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,overall mark.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps share with us your code showing what you've tried?

Comment: And how your text file is formatted will be very useful.

Comment: As @Steve said, the biggest question is your text file's format and the amount of data... Based upon those things, you would choose the correct way to deal with it...

Comment: Looks like a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621756/importing-txt-file-and-manipulating-string-to-do-calculations/15625202#15625202

Comment: As others have suggested, you need to provide more details such as the format of the text file, the expected size of the file, and how you intend to use the data.  As I'm sure you realize, there are many ways to skin a cat, so without more details, it's impossible to answer.  If you don't provide more details, the question will likely be closed soon.

Comment: The list is saved as a txt file, students are seperated by commmas as follows name,grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,overall mark.

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate of the question referred to by @JoelCoehoorn.  Have you tried the suggestion in his answer to that question?  If so, can you show the code you have tried and explain more specifically what problems you are running into?

Comment: look into [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: I have the streamreader iterating through the text file but I can't get it to average out the results only display the first result. The grade results are seperated by a comma I have the delimiter set but can't get the average function to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class with the required properties and then create a list(of Object). Please see below for an example.

```
Public Sub GetStudentData()
    Dim oStudents As New List(Of Student)
    Using r As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("file.txt")
        ' Store contents in this String.
        Dim line As String

        ' Read first line.
        line = r.ReadLine
        oStudents.Add(New Student(line))
        Do While (line IsNot Nothing)
            ' Read in the next line.
            line = r.ReadLine
            oStudents.Add(New Student(line))
        Loop
    End Using
End Sub

Public Class Student
    Public Property StudentID As String
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property HighestGrade As String
    Public Property Averages As String
    Public Property OverAllMarks As String

    Public Sub New(line As String)
        _StudentID = line ' Get specific string from text line
        _FirstName = line ' Get specific string from text line
        _LastName = line ' Get specific string from text line
        _HighestGrade = line ' Get specific string from text line
        _Averages = line ' Get specific string from text line
        _OverAllMarks = line ' Get specific string from text line
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub btnAverage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAverage.Click

```
    Using myreader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\Users\documents\studentresults.txt")
        myreader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        myreader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentrow As String()
        While Not myreader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentrow = myreader.ReadFields()
                Dim average As Double
                currentrow.Skip(1).Skip(2).Average(Function(s) Convert.ToDouble(s))
                MsgBox("Average is " & currentrow(0))
                Convert.ToString(average)
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("line" & ex.Message &
                       "is not valid and will be skipped")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

This is the code I have so far so any suggestions would be great.